# ¿Cómo puedo sumar minutos a una hora en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una lista con los siguientes datos `var horario = [inicio:"6:30", fin:"9:30", lapso:"20"]`. Se inicia a las 6:30, siendo el lapso el espacio entre horas. La magnitud del lapso son minutos. Al pulsar el botón Imprimir, la función comenzará a sumar de 20 en 20 minutos la hora, iniciando con las 6:30 en este caso. En la variable horas, será el conjunto de horas resultantes de sumar el lapso. No funciona la suma de horas, estas deben tratarse como horas y no como números.

```js
var horario = [inicio:"6:30", fin:"9:30", lapso:"20"]
var horas;//El conjunto de horas
var horaSiguiente;

function imprimir(){
  //horaSiguiente es el primer valor
  horaSiguiente = horario["inicio"];
  
  //Bucle que sumará el lapso que sea hasta que la hora sea igual a la final indicada en la lista
  while(horaSiguiente != horario["fin"];){
    horaSiguiente += horario["lapso"];
    horas += horaSiguiente;
  }
  console.log(horas)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="imprimir()">Imprimir</button>
```

El resultado final debería ser:

```
6:30
6:50
7:10
7:30
7:50
8:10
8:30
8:50
9:10
9:30
```

Comment: Podrías poner esos datos en un `Date` y [manipularlos](https://javascript.info/date) allí mucho más fácil. Ya si después quieres obtener sólo la hora, pues usar los getters

Answer (score 0):

En javaScript se usa el tipo de datos Date para trabajar con las fechas y horas, puedes usar este para trabajar con las misma.
Te dejo un ejemplo con los pasos comentado, fíjate que hice un método el cual uso para sumar los minutos a la hora.

```
// agragar un metodo al prototype del string de js
String.prototype.setMinuto = function(minuto)
{
  // sacar la hora y los minutos del string
  let horaMinuto = this.split(':');

  // llevarla a tipo data para poder tratarlo
  let horaAsDate = new Date(0,0,0,Number(horaMinuto[0]), Number(horaMinuto[1]),0);

  // el resultado de la hora con los minutos sumados
  let resultado = new Date(horaAsDate.getTime() + minuto*60000);

  // salida de la nueva hora
  return `${resultado.getHours()}:${resultado.getMinutes()}`;
};

var horario = {inicio:"6:30", fin:"9:30", lapso:"20"};
var horas=[horario.inicio];//El conjunto de horas
var horaSiguiente = '';

function imprimir(){
  //horaSiguiente es el primer valor
  horaSiguiente = horario.inicio;

  //Bucle que sumará el lapso que sea hasta que la hora sea igual a la final indicada en la lista
  while(horaSiguiente != horario.fin){
    horaSiguiente = horaSiguiente.setMinuto(horario.lapso);
    horas.push(horaSiguiente);
  }
  console.table(horas);
}
```

Botón

```
<button onclick="imprimir()">Imprimir</button>
```